# Processing flattened JSON prior to SQL Server 2016

Tags: json, sql-server, flatten

We have a pre-2016 SQL Server.

We have JSON objects which have been flattened like this:

```
const obj = { "Event": {
"EventId": "3753f9fb-114e-48e7-aade-29c70e6c020e",
"Id": "1057a404-dbf2-4be8-8f3d-138912991ef5",
"Timestamp": "2021-12-23T03:36:29Z",
"EventData": {
    "ItemData": {
        "ItemId": 4335549,
        "CustID": "xyz123",
        "dateCreated": "2021-02-01 07:50:51.1670000",
        "amount": 10.99,
        "pData": [
            {"date": "2021-02-01",
             "price":19.99,
             "color": "red"},
            {"date": "2021-01-01",
             "price":15.23,
             "color": "green"}
        ]
    }
}
}}

const flattenJSON = (obj = {}, res = {}, extraKey = '') => {
    for(key in obj){
       if(typeof obj[key] !== 'object'){
          res[extraKey + key] = obj[key];
       }else{
          flattenJSON(obj[key], res, `${extraKey}${key}.`);
       };
    };
    return res;
 };
 console.log(JSON.stringify(flattenJSON(obj)));
```

From that, we get this:

```
{
"Event.EventId": "3753f9fb-114e-48e7-aade-29c70e6c020e",
"Event.Id": "1057a404-dbf2-4be8-8f3d-138912991ef5",
"Event.Timestamp": "2021-12-23T03:36:29Z",
"Event.EventData.ItemData.ItemId": 4335549,
"Event.EventData.ItemData.CustID": "xyz123",
"Event.EventData.ItemData.dateCreated": "2021-02-01 07:50:51.1670000",
"Event.EventData.ItemData.amount": 10.99,
"Event.EventData.ItemData.pData.0.date": "2021-02-01",
"Event.EventData.ItemData.pData.0.price": 19.99,
"Event.EventData.ItemData.pData.0.color": "red",
"Event.EventData.ItemData.pData.1.date": "2021-01-01",
"Event.EventData.ItemData.pData.1.price": 15.23,
"Event.EventData.ItemData.pData.1.color": "green"
}
```

We understand that upgrading to 2016 is the best solution, and we'd get all the JSON functionality there.

But barring the ability to do that, is there a good way to take the flattened result above and insert into tables? Or is there perhaps a different way to flatten the initial JSON and pass into an SP to "table-ize?"

Comment: Serialised JSON is just a string. Without native JSON functions, you just need to cook up the right string manipulation to grab required data.

Comment: "is there a good way to take the flattened result above and insert into tables?" Insert into tables from C#? or insert into one table from another? Can you narrow down the requirement? I don't see any requirement for SQL Server side code here.

Comment: One table, two tables, three tables, more? While I can see from the JSON what the _columns_ are, it's tough to tell how this data ends up in multiple tables (and then has relations between them). The C# code that _gets_ the JSON is far less important than the destination JSON (though I do agree the better option would be to not create JSON you can't process directly in the first place, and just insert the data from C# (with, you know, insert statements and parameters) without bothering with JSON at all).

Comment: Aside... it's not just upgrading to SQL Server 2016 or later that gets you JSON operations, in your own user databases, it's actually upgrading the compatibility level of those user databases to 130 or beyond. Upgrading SQL Server to a newer version doesn't automatically upgrade the compatibility level of your databases because that has many other affects besides enabling JSON support.